# How to spawn the wither

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I saw on youtube that the wither is hard to beat, so I thought I would attempt to kill one to prove I'm better than it. After searching "Wither", it only came up with a wither skeleton. How do I spawn the wither, and how to I make the spawner?

Comment: Good luck. He is mental hard. Ensure you have some badass enchantments and ample space to move about before you take him on

Comment: After searching wither it only says a wither skeletion? I should've took you right to the wither mob or the *witherstorm*.

Answer (score 17):

To spawn a Wither you need to build it like with Golems (Snow and Iron), you need 4 Soul Sand in a T Shape and 3 Wither Skeleton Heads on top of the top 3 Soul Sand Blocks [More Info here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wither), when it's made it'll cause an explosion and the fight is on

Comment: Doesn't seem to explode if you spawn it from the egg in creative mode...

Answer (score 9):

As Memor-X said, you can spawn a Wither with 4 Soul Sand and 3 Wither Skeleton Heads.

However, if you desire to spawn the wither by "unlegit" means you can use the command:

```
/Summon WitherBoss
```

This instantly spawns a Wither Boss in front of you.

Obviously you have to have commands enabled to use this command.

Answer (score 1):

Make a T out of 4 pieces of soulsand and place three wither skulls across the top of the T.

This will create a wither. It will charge for a moment then explode, so RUN! Then it will start exploding the land around it so dont do it in your house. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You can spawn a Wither by placing 4 soul sand and 3 wither skeleton skulls like this:

```
SS: Soul sand | WSS: Wither skeleton skull

|WSS|WSS|WSS|
|SS |SS |SS |
|   |SS |   |
```